# shinydashboard: MenuSubItem text as downloadLink

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I haven't been able to find any solutions yet. Is it possible to trigger a `downloadHandler` when the `text` of a `menuSubItem` is clicked? So the same behavior as if it was a `downloadLink`? I tried a few things like:
 `text = downloadLink("dl_object1", "Download object1")`
 or 
`text = shiny::tags$html(downloadLink("dl_object1", "Download object1"))`
 or 
`text = shiny::htmlOutput("<a id='dl_object1' class='shiny-download-link'>Download object1</a>")`

however the result is either the text being rendered incorrectly as a `subMenuItem` or not return a download dialog on click.

Here's an example app to test with:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem(
          text = "Working download",
          icon = icon("download"),
          downloadLink(
            outputId = "dl_object1",
            label = "Download object1"
          ),
          tags$p(),
          downloadLink(
            outputId = "dl_object2",
            label = "Download object2"
          )
        ),
        menuItem(
          text = "Not working download",
          icon = icon("download"),
          menuSubItem(
            tabName = NULL,
            text = shiny::tags$html("<a id='dl_object1' class='shiny-download-link'>Download object1</a>")
          ),
          menuSubItem(
            tabName = NULL,
            text = shiny::tags$html("<a id='dl_object2' class='shiny-download-link'>Download object2</a>")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    body = dashboardBody()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    #object1
    output$dl_object1 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0("object1.csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(iris[1:10,], file = file)
      }
    )
    #object2
    output$dl_object2 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0("object2.csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(iris[11:20,], file = file)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

I have also posted this as an issue on the RStudio GitHub, but so far no answer. https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/265

Answer (score 1):

The following workaround works in IE, Chrome, Firefox, but not in Safari 12.0:

1. place `downloadLink("dl_object1", ...)` somewhere in ui.R where it works when you click it
2. hide the downloadLink, f.i. by: `document.getElementById("dl_object1").style.visibility = 'hidden';`
3. On clicking the menu item perform `document.getElementById("dl_object1").click();`